# Truffle Pet Shop Example:

Tags: truffle

I am working through the pet shop tutorial in the Truffle Suite documentation and am hitting a error and have been looking at it for a while.

What is it that actually produces the DeployedAddresses.sol?  In my case it is not getting produced, due to some error somewhere on my part.

The output of the truffle test is included below.

````
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\test\TestAdoption.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\test--22492-b1Oa5KHqOkGz
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



  TestAdoption
    √ testUserCanAdoptPet (641ms)
    √ testGetAdopterAddressByPetId (259ms)
    √ testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray (305ms)

  Contract: Adoption
    1) can fetch the collection of all pet owners' addresses
    > No events were emitted
    adopting a pet and retrieving account addresses
      √ can fetch the address of an owner by pet id (83ms)


  4 passing (16s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Adoption
       can fetch the collection of all pet owners' addresses:
     ReferenceError: expectedAdopter is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\testAdoption.test.js:31:7)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not declare expectedAdopter as address and set it equal to `address(this)` in your test file.
or maybe typo somewhere